# Tooltip per pixel

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I'd like that, when you hover the mouse over a pixel in an `img`, you see a tooltip showing you which pixel (X,Y) you are over.  How can I do this? I need to be able to capture two things:

1. That they are hovering
2. The current coordinate of the mouse, with respect to the pixel of the image

Note that I want this to be in terms of the (x,y) of the _original) img, even if their browser is zooming it

Answer (score 0):

this code snippet might helpful to you, copy this code to new html file and test it

```js
window.onmousemove = function() {
  var toolitp = document.getElementById("tooltip");
  toolitp.style.top = window.event.clientY + "px";
  toolitp.style.left = window.event.clientX + "px";
  toolitp.innerHTML = " X: " + window.event.clientX + " Y: " + window.event.clientY;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100px; height: 15px; top:0; left: 0; position: absolute; border: 1px solid black;" id="tooltip"></div>
```

Comment: toolitp.style.top = window.event.clientY `+ "px"`; or it won't work

Comment: Thanks - but that's relative to the whole window; I'd like it relative to the img (in terms of the img's pixels, irrespective of browser zoom or img location in the page or window)